# how to use UISearchController IOS8.0

Tags: ios

The UISearchDisplayController is deprecated in IOS8.0

And now I want to use UISearchController to implement a location search APP

I want to implement the search suggestion list after user type some words in the search bar.

So far I have already completed the suggestion result from the server but I don't know how to display it.

The app gets a search suggestion result everytime in

```
-(void)searchBar:(UISearchBar *)searchBar textDidChange:(NSString *)searchText
```

And I store the result in to ResultArray.
But how can I show the result on screen? After I assigned a tableview to the *searchResultsController.view* property, the result list still cannot be shown

Many Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) UISearchController *searchController;
```

**Now in the viewDidLoad method we can create and setup the search controller.**

```
self.searchController = [[UISearchController alloc] initWithSearchResultsController:nil];
self.searchController.searchResultsUpdater = self;
self.searchController.dimsBackgroundDuringPresentation = NO;
self.searchController.searchBar.scopeButtonTitles = @[NSLocalizedString(@"ScopeButtonCountry",@"Country"),
                                                      NSLocalizedString(@"ScopeButtonCapital",@"Capital")];
self.searchController.searchBar.delegate = self;
```

**Next we add the search bar view to the table view header:**

```
self.tableView.tableHeaderView = self.searchController.searchBar;

[self.searchController.searchBar sizeToFit];
```

UISearchResultsUpdating Delegate

With the search controller configured the rest is mostly boilerplate code. We need to implement the UISearchResultsUpdating delegate to generate the new filtered results anytime the search text changes:

```
- (void)updateSearchResultsForSearchController:(UISearchController *)searchController
{
  NSString *searchString = searchController.searchBar.text;
  [self searchForText:searchString scope:searchController.searchBar.selectedScopeButtonIndex];
  [self.tableView reloadData];
}
```

**UISearchBarDelegate - Scope Bar**

```
- (void)searchBar:(UISearchBar *)searchBar selectedScopeButtonIndexDidChange:(NSInteger)selectedScope
{
  [self updateSearchResultsForSearchController:self.searchController];
}
```

AND FOre MOre YOu cane..
[Learn From here](https://coderwall.com/p/sijizw/search-mechanism-in-ios-8)

[image]

## Another way i have added Another Solution, take a look May be useful to you.

*First add the UISearchDisplayController to your table view Then set     its delegate.
Implement the following methods.*

[Demo Project](https://www.dropbox.com/s/jg0f2bx7e30ld22/Search%20Table%20Sample.zip?dl=0)

```
In your .h File

    @interface ViewController : UIViewController <UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource> {

    NSMutableArray *contentList;
    NSMutableArray *filteredContentList;
    BOOL isSearching;
}
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITableView *tblContentList;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UISearchBar *searchBar;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UISearchDisplayController *searchBarController;
In your .m File

Filling the sample data (Optional Only For Demo Purpose)

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    contentList = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"iPhone", @"iPod", @"iPod touch", @"iMac", @"Mac Pro", @"iBook",@"MacBook", @"MacBook Pro", @"PowerBook", nil];
    filteredContentList = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
}
Now implement the Table View Delegate and Datasource

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {

    // Return the number of sections.
    return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    // Return the number of rows in the section.
    if (isSearching) {
        return [filteredContentList count];
    }
    else {
        return [contentList count];
    }
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    }

    // Configure the cell...
    if (isSearching) {
        cell.textLabel.text = [filteredContentList objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    }
    else {
        cell.textLabel.text = [contentList objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    }
    return cell;

}
Search Function Responsible For Searching

- (void)searchTableList {
    NSString *searchString = searchBar.text;

    for (NSString *tempStr in contentList) {
        NSComparisonResult result = [tempStr compare:searchString options:(NSCaseInsensitiveSearch|NSDiacriticInsensitiveSearch) range:NSMakeRange(0, [searchString length])];
        if (result == NSOrderedSame) {
            [filteredContentList addObject:tempStr];
        }
    }
}
Search Bar Implementation

- (void)searchBarTextDidBeginEditing:(UISearchBar *)searchBar {
    isSearching = YES;
}

- (void)searchBar:(UISearchBar *)searchBar textDidChange:(NSString *)searchText {
    NSLog(@"Text change - %d",isSearching);

    //Remove all objects first.
    [filteredContentList removeAllObjects];

    if([searchText length] != 0) {
        isSearching = YES;
        [self searchTableList];
    }
    else {
        isSearching = NO;
    }
    // [self.tblContentList reloadData];
}

- (void)searchBarCancelButtonClicked:(UISearchBar *)searchBar {
    NSLog(@"Cancel clicked");
}

- (void)searchBarSearchButtonClicked:(UISearchBar *)searchBar {
    NSLog(@"Search Clicked");
    [self searchTableList];
}
```

Comment: it looks like some of this answer was copied from http://useyourloaf.com/blog/updating-to-the-ios-8-search-controller.html and should probably give some credit (unless, of course, that is your website)

Comment: everything is in internet, you can search. Here i am helping those who did not have that much talent. they need help and i will do that. if you have any problem then its your problem. i dont have any website. and  i do not need. if you have time and talent then show here. you will get reputation as we all getting. ok. @zonabi. dont take it personally. but i hurt you then sorry..

Comment: it's all good @mehul we all certainly appreciate your and everyone's help. it is just common courtesy to credit anytime you copy from somewhere.

Comment: @zonabi, r u IOS developer ?